# Virtual Destructor Test Fails

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived1 : protected Base {};
class Derived2 : protected Derived1{};
class Derived3 : protected Derived2{};

int main() {
    Base* b[] = {new Base, new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
    delete[] b;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following compilation errors and I was only following what I was taught:

> Warning    1   warning C4624: 'Derived1' : destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible or deleted
>
> Warning    2   warning C4624: 'Derived2' : destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible or deleted
>
> Warning    3   warning C4624: 'Derived3' : destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible or deleted
>
> Error  4   error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived1 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible
>
> Error  5   error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived2 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible
>
> Error  6   error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived3 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible
>
> Warning   7   warning C4154: deletion of an array expression; conversion to pointer supplied
>
> 8  IntelliSense: conversion to inaccessible base class "Base" is not allowed
>
> 9  IntelliSense: conversion to inaccessible base class "Derived1" is not allowed
>
> 10 IntelliSense: conversion to inaccessible base class "Derived2" is not allowed

Comment: There is no question here and no guideline about what should be done or the contraint you have.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue 1**

Put the destructor in `public` section of `Base`.

```
class Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Base {
  private:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Change it to:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

**Issue 2**

```
Base* b[] = {new Base, new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
```

constructs the objects by using the `new` operator three times. You need to call `delete` three times -- once for each pointer.

Instead of

```
delete[] b;
```

use

```
delete b[0];
delete b[1];
delete b[2];
```

**Issue 3**

To be able to use

```
Base* p = new Derived1;
```

You have to make `Base` a `public` base class of `Derived1`, not `protected`.

Change

```
class Derived1 : protected Base {};
class Derived2 : protected Derived1{};
class Derived3 : protected Derived2{};
```

to

```
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Derived1{};
class Derived3 : public Derived2{};
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived1 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible

Comment: Error 2 error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived2 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible

Comment: Error 3 error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'Derived3 *' to 'Base *' exists, but is inaccessible

Comment: @BloodBrother That's the third point in my answer. You can't say `Base * p = new Derived1` unless `Derived1` inherits publicly from `Base`.

Comment: The problem is with protected inheritance but how do I fix it?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Please see my latest comment.

Comment: @RSahu: I'm requred to use protected inheritance my friend. That's a constraint.

Comment: @BloodBrother, then you may not use `Base* b[] = {new Derived1};`. You can still use `Derived1* p = new Derived1;`.

Comment: Thank you so much @RSahu. You were unbelievably helpful as always. I love you man.

Answer (score 3):

You have three big problems:

First of all, you are misusing `delete[]`. It is meant to be called when you allocate an array with `new []`. You haven't done that. You need to loop over array `b`, calling `delete` on each element.

Second, your `Base` virtual destructor is `private`. It needs to be accessible to the derived types, so make it `public`.

Third, so `DerivedN` *is-a* `Base`, you need to make the inheritance `public`. Without this you can't assign or initialize a pointer to a Derived object to a pointer to Base.

Here is a fixed version:

```
class Base {
 public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Derived1{};
class Derived3 : public Derived2{};

int main()
{
    Base* b[] = {new Base, new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
    for (auto p : b) delete p;
}
```

Comment: I'm required to use protected. How do I modify the code to accommodate this?

Comment: @BloodBrother Strictly speaking, the code doesn't do anything, so you can remove it all leaving only an empty `main()` function. In practice, it depends on what you want to achieve with the real code you're trying to fix.

Comment: I'm required to use protected inheritance and access all objects using the base class pointer. It's an order to me. Period.

Comment: That's a positively ridiculous requirement.  Which means either you're making it up, or whoever ordered you doesn't know what they are doing.  By using protected inheritance, conversion of pointers to an instance of any derived class into a pointer to base is prevented when creating the array b in main().    The only solution to that would be to declare main() as a friend of all the classes - which completely defeats any point of using protected inheritence.

Comment: This is my assignment. Tell my instructor he's ridiculous.

Comment: @BloodBrother If your instructor told you something, then either (1) the question miss important information from the assignment, (2) he want you to discover the problem or (3) if want you to find a solution for that (in which case, the solution really depends on what you should have learn at this point). **We have to see the assignment** to be able to properly help you.